# What is the best way to download a new Ubuntu release?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, live-cd, bittorrent, download-speed

I like having a live cd to boot from (i'm presuming you can upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 from the live cd) in case of any problems, as i'm a bit of a fiddler, so i'd like to know if direct download (ubuntu.com, mirror) or a torrent would be the fastest way on day one?

I know this is probably subjective, depending on how many people are doing each, but really i'm worried about the stability of a large download. I'd like it done faster, but if direct is likely to slow down or have an error i'll torrent.

Did the network have any errors during downloads on the release of 11.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually torrents are the best way, as mirrors always see a *huge* bandwidth spike on release day. Another good way to have an up to date system on release day is install the release candidate and allow it to update on its own. The servers will be less congested, and the differences will be minimal.

Of course, torrenting allows you to give back to the community as well :)